# How to install php zip extensions in cyberpanel

Tags: php, vps, cyber-panel

I am getting an error like this when installing the php zip extension

[image]

I tried everything in the internet but nothing worked.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you

Comment: The image you shared doesn't show an error it just shows a success message

Comment: Suggest to run a check via ```phpinfo()``` to check whether it has been installed or not.

Comment: Yes the zip file is showing but it is not enabled

Comment: did you already close this question?

cz i got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue for many days but then I tried this and I was able to get the extension installed in my Cyberpanel for PHP version 8.0.

Edit **php.ini**, Login to your **Cyberpanel** > **Edit PHP Configuration** > **Advanced** > **PHP 8.0**

Add **extension=zip.so** at the bottom of the document.

and now run the commands:

```
# yum install lsphp80-zip

# /usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/pecl install zip

# killall lsphp

# php -m | grep zip
```

With this, I was able to resolve the issue and get the ZIP extension installed in my Cyberpanel. I hope this will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instructions for installing PHP extensions in CyberPanel for users who cannot find the desired extensions in the `Server > PHP > Install Extensions` section or in the LiteSpeed repository.

In such cases, you can use the PEAR package manager to manage PECL 17 extensions. First, change "lsphp74" to your default PHP version and run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
./lsphp go-pear.phar
```

Once PEAR is installed, you can install the required extension. For example, to install the latest version of the zip extension, use the following command:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/pecl install zip
```

If you need a specific version of the zip extension, you can install it using this command:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/pecl install zip-1.21.1
```

Note: Make sure to add `extension=zip.so` to your .php config

Remember to replace "lsphp74" with the PHP version you have installed as the default. This should help you install the PHP extensions you need in CyberPanel.